# A question about the *product topology*.

Tags: general-topology

I would like to know how to give the product topology to the set $$\left[0, 1\right]^{X} = \{f: X \rightarrow \left[0, 1\right]: f \text{ is a function}\},$$ where $X$ is a random set.

Comment: What is your definition of function? Is it related to some kind of  product?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the usual product topology defined by the subbasis of sets of the form 
$$\mathcal{F}_{x,U}=\{f\in[0,1]^X\mid f(x)\in U\},$$ where $x\in X$ is a given point and $U\subseteq[0,1]$ is open?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: This space is a product of topological spaces, hence, has the product topology. What else do you want to know.

Comment: @studiosus I want to understand **why** it is a product of topological spaces. That's the part I don't see.

Comment: Do you know definition of product of sets? This is just the space of functions, like in this example. To the best of my knowledge, there are no other definitions if X is arbitrary.

Comment: It might help if you realized that $[0,1]^n$ is a set of functions. While it is often thought of as the set of sequences $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ such that each of the $x_1,…,x_n$ is in $[0,1]$, a sequence **is** a function. So, $[0,1]^n$ is the set of all functions with domain $\{1,2,…,n\}$ and range $[0,1]$.

Comment: Three of your most recent questions have "question about" in the title. Please avoid this in the future. Everyone knows that this site contains question, not poems or tweets. Instead, it is better to make the title more specific: e.g., "How to define product topology on a set of functions?"

Answer (score 4):

The cartesian product $\prod_{x\in X}[0,1]$ of copies of $[0,1]$ indexed by the set $X$ is, *by definition*, the set of functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$. This is a cartesian product of topological spaces. Therefore it fits into the general formalism of product topologies. If $I$ is a set and for each $i\in I$, we have a topological space $X_i$, then the product topology on the cartesian product $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is, by definition, the coarsest topology with respect to which the projection maps $\pi_j:(x_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto x_j:\prod_i X_i\to X_j$ are continuous. Concretely, a base of open sets for this topology consists of the sets of the form $\prod_i U_i$, where $U_i\subseteq X_i$ is open in $X_i$ for all $i$, and for all but finitely many $i$, $U_i=X_i$.

The product topology on the space of functions $[0,1]^X=\prod_{x\in X}[0,1]$ is, by its definition, the topology of pointwise convergence. That is, a net of functions $(f_\alpha)_\alpha$ in $[0,1]^X$ converges to $f\in[0,1]^X$ if and only if for each $x\in X$, $f_\alpha(x)\to f(x)$ in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean to say arbitrary set. To define a basic open set take a a finite number of elements from $X$, $x_1, ...x_n$ and a finite set of open subsets of $[0,1]$, $U_1, ...U_n$ then a basic open  set is all functions such that $f(x_i) \in U_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The projections from $[0,1]^X$ to $[0,1]$ are exactly all the maps $p_x: [0,1]^X \rightarrow [0,1]$ for $x \in X$, defined by $p_x(f) = f(x)$.

The product topology is the smallest topology that makes all $p_x$ continuous.

So this topology is generated by all sets $(p_x)^{-1}[U] = \{f \in [0,1]^X: f(x) \in U \}$, where $x$ ranges over all $x \in X$ and $U$ over all non-empty subsets of $[0,1]$. In fact, we could suffice by taking all $U$ from any fixed base for the topology of $[0,1]$, if we like. A base is then generated by taking all finite intersections of members of this subbase.

This means that one way to describe the basic open sets of $[0,1]^X$ is as follows: we pick finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ from $X$ and finitely many open sets $U_1,\ldots,U_N \subset [0,1]$, and then a basic open set is of the form $\{f \in [0,1]^X: \text{ for } i = 1 \ldots N: f(x_i) \in U_i \}$.

So basic open sets determine the values at finitely many points, and leave all other values unspecified.

Another way to put it: a net $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ in $[0,1]^X$ converges to $f$ iff for all $x \in X$, we have that the net $(f_i(x))_{i \in I}$ converges to $f(x)$.